# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

Iam refactoring and adding some features to an old project, but when i open the project i got an compilation error:

```
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
       > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

And with gradlew clean assembleDebug i have got the full error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProjectName'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.1.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

And this is the java version:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi"
    }
```

And this is build.gradle module level:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.48.1' apply false
}
```

I have searched a lot and tried many things but no result.

And this is what i have tried:

- Downgrade and Upgrade AGP version.
- Downgrade and Upgrade kotlin version.
- Use different jdk versions such as 11, 1.8 and 17.

I hope anyone have a solution. Thanks in advance.